# Tail Sampling Logs

Tags: bash, tail

I have a process that needs to do periodic processing on an ever-growing logfile. Right now, the way I do this is pretty simple (I'll include the bash script if you're truly curious).

- Start up tail -n0 -f $FILE
- Each iteration:

  - Kill the tail
  - Move the old sample
  - Start up a new tail

This solves for the problem of not having any overlap, but I'm worried about the 1 or 2 lines I might miss. Is there a better way of doing this to that avoids overlap (and "under"lap)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "move the old sample", I assume you mean rotating the file by moving the current one away and replacing it with a new file.

If so, then you could use the `--follow=name` option for `tail` instead of `-f`. This follows the file by name rather than the file descriptor, which allows it to continue even if the files is replaced. You can then leave your `tail` running while you replace the files and not miss any entries.

For a more robust approach also include `--retry`, or simply use `-F` which implies `--follow=name --retry`.

From the man page:

> **`-f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]`**
>
> > output appended data as the file grows; `-f`, `--follow`, and `--follow=descriptor` are equivalent
>
> **`--retry`**
>
> > keep trying to open a file even if it is inaccessible when tail starts or if  it  becomes  inaccessible later - useful only with `-f`
>
> **`-F`**
>
> > same as `--follow=name --retry`

Comment: I have to agree! This can be so much useful. +1 to the question and the answer!

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind, but works nonetheless. Thank you!